Using keyboard.read_key to quit a program on a condition
I'm trying to add functionality to my first project, a number guessing game. I want to allow the user to either enter a number to guess, or press escape to exit the program.
I've contained an if else conditional within a try block, at the point that the user provides input. I feel I have semantic error that I can't quite place, as the quit condition works upon first entering the while loop, but not in any further iterations.
I suspect there is other ways I can make this code more concise, and creating some functions is on my short-term to do list.
Any feedback appreciated,
Cheers.
generatedNumber = rand.randint(1,10)

while True: 
    try:    
            # prompt the user for their input
            print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10.")

            # read the users keystroke and if it is equal to 'esc'
            if keyboard.read_key(suppress=True) == 'esc':
                #close the program
                print("The program will now close.")
                quit()

            else: # otherwise
                #read their guessed number
                userInput = int(input())  

    except ValueError:
        print("Your input was invalid.")
        continue        
    if userInput < 1 or userInput > 10:
        print("Your guess should be a number between 1 and 10.")  
        continue  
    if userInput > generatedNumber:
        print("Your guess was too high.")
        continue
    if  userInput < generatedNumber:
        print("Your guess was too low.") 
        continue
    if userInput == generatedNumber:
        print("Congratulations! Your guess was correct.")
        break

print("The game is now over.")
exit()


The problem you have is a conflict between the read_key function and input because if ESC is not entered then another character is expected and this then affects the input call. Although there are complicated low-level ways to deal with this it would be much simpler just to accept say Q to quit and pick this up after input before the conversion to int
